# Create rolling window from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am playing with time series data, and I want to train a model to predict future outcomes. I have some data shaped like the following:

```
Date    Failures
0   2021-06 10
1   2021-05 2
2   2021-04 7
3   2021-03 9
4   2021-02 3
...
```

I would like to shape this data, not necessarily a pandas df, as a rolling window with four entries:

```
10 2 7 9 3
...
```

and then the fifth entry being the number I want to predict. I have read on stack exchange that one wants to avoid iterating over pandas DataFrame, so what would be the appropriate manner to transform my dataframe? I have heard of `.rolling` method, however, this does not seem to achieve what I want.

Comment: what *do* you want? rolling and iterating over rows could be appropriate depending on your use case. but "predict" is pretty vague - can you show us what you've tried and what's not working?

Comment: Is the provided output complete? Or just for row 0?

Comment: I want to train this time series data on a neural network . I'd like to format the data such that we have: `x11 x12 x13 x14 y1` and so on for each row. So I'd like to convert, for example, a `(245, 1)` shape into a `(49, 5)` shape. It seems normally that you would just iterate over these entries and construct a new dataframe, however, it appears this is not efficient whatsoever with pandas. To be more specific, I am wondering if there is a method I can use to get the desired shape specified above, or if I should convert my dataframe to a non pandas type and then iterate.

Comment: @mozway the provided output is not complete, it is just a snippet of what I would like the first row to be. In totality, I want to convert a tall and skinny matrix into a wider, shorter matrix

Comment: Will be better to give a sample input and output dataframe, with some assumed (simple) extrapolation function so it is easy for readers to understand what exactly is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want to reshape you column to shape (49,5) when it has an initial length of 245. You can use the underlying numpy array:

```
df['Failures'].values.reshape(-1,5)
```

Output (dummy numbers):

```
array([[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4],
       [  5,   6,   7,   8,   9],
       [ 10,  11,  12,  13,  14],
       [ 15,  16,  17,  18,  19],
       ...
       [235, 236, 237, 238, 239],
       [240, 241, 242, 243, 244]])
```